# Rails: collection_select naming method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Does anyone know of a way to get `collection_select` to name its fields for the text methods' names and not their values?

I've got `print_100`, `print_200`, and `print_500` and a plan to add more when necessary. I'd like the values of the select box to read from `Billing` all the fields that start with `print_` so the select box would just have options like `100`, `200`, and `500`.

```
f.collection_select(:print_quantity, Billing.all, :print_100, :print_100)
```

Any thoughts? Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @DavidDraughnn for the idea for this solution. I wrote a method in the relevant helper, thus:

```
def get_quantities
  @quantities = {}
  Billing.column_names.each do |a|
    if a.match(/^print_/)
      @quantities[a.delete "print_"] = a.delete "print_"
    end
  end
  return @quantities
end
```

And I've adjusted `collection_select` to `select`, thus:

```
<% get_quantities %>
<%= f.select(:print_quantity, @quantities, {:prompt => "Please select..."}) %>
```

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not as familiar with this part of rails as I'd like to be, so be gentle.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select

the syntax is
    collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})

If you were to change the second parameter (`method`) to an actual method (rather than just the attribute that you want from the billing object) you can make the value whatever you would like.

If that doesn't work (or if you're not allowed to substitute the attribute for a method) then you may be able to make it work using the 5th or 6th parameters, `value_method` and `text_method`, which define what values should be applied to the tags.

Anyway, this answer is mostly to point you in (hopefully) the right direction, since I'm not certain of the method or how it works.

Good luck.

Comment: That's not a bad idea at all. I'll do some investigation. Cheers.

Comment: With your suggestion I solved it! I'll write the solution in an answer and not a comment so I can format it properly.